# making a function as an else inside an __init__

Tags: python, tornado

How to get a function inside `if/else` inside an `__init__` :

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, q, **keywords):
        if a == "":
            print "No empty strings"
        else:
            def on_g(self, response):
                if response.error:
                    print "Check your internet settings"
                else:
                    self.Bar()
            http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", self.on_g)
```

because the program dont read the `on_g()` if i put an empty string!

If i use the `on_g()` outside in parallel with `__init__()` i need a declared variable, for example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, q, **keywords):
        if a == "":
            print "No empty strings"
        else:
            self.on_g()
   def on_g(self):
       print 'hello there'
```

will return `hello there`

Comment: what is `a`? id does not to seem to be declared anywhere.

Comment: `a` is declared, but the problem is it dont want to get inside the else when i use the `callback` system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` (the instance you're creating through `__init__` ) doesn't have a `on_g` method.

Functions for the `class`-es need to be defined at the `class` level (as shown on your second chunk of code). They are evaluated when the `class` is first... erm... "looked-up"? "evaluated"?

That's why your second piece of code works. How come you can call `self.on_g` within the `__init__` when the actual definition of the `on_g` method *seems* to come later in the code? It's an odd behavior (at a first glance) for an interpreter, right? Well... That's because when you run `self.on_g()`, the whole `Foo` class has already been evaluated and `on_g` has been added to the `class` (not to the `instance`!: To the `class`)

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self, q, **keywords):
       [ . . . ]
       else:
           self.on_g()      # I can use self.on_g() eventhough is defined... _
                            #                                                 |
                            #                                                 |
   def on_g(self):          # <------------ LATER  ---------------------------|
       print 'hello there'
```

Whereas if you define your method within the `__init__`, the interpreter will yell at you:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        def test(self):
            print "Hello"
        self.test()

a = Test()
```

Throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 10, in <module>
    a = Test()
  File "./test.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.test()
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'test'
```

Even if you think *Oh, maybe the class doesn't have the `test` method because it's still within the __init__, and it will have it once the initialization is completed*... Meeeck... Wrong:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        def test(self):
            print "Hello"

a = Test()
a.test()
```

Same `AttributeError`.

If you still want to add `on_g` to the `class` at runtime (very bad idea, IMHO) you can do the interpreter's job by doing this:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        def test(self):
            print "Hello"
        self.__class__.test = test
        self.test()

a = Test()
a.test()
```

... which correctly prints:

```
Hello
Hello
```

Now, the two most straightforward things to do I can think of are:

1. You move the `def on_g(self)` to the `class` level (as you showed in your second code snippet)
2. You call your `http_client.fetch` with `on_g` as a *function* local to the `__init__`'s scope (being picky with the language: `on_g` now is a *function*, not a *method*, since is not bound to an object anymore).

   ```
   def __init__(self, q, **keywords):
       if a == "":
           print "No empty strings"
       else:
           def on_g(response):
               if response.error:
                   print "Check your internet settings"
               else:
                   self.Bar()
           http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", on_g)
   ```

Comment: ah, i think that now the OOP is no more a magic for me! thank you!

Comment: No problem... And thanks for consider this the *accepted answer* But be prepared: Once you start dealing with OOP, you're bound to discover a lot of new stuff. Fun stuff!! **:-D** (yeah, seriously fun) Enjoy!!

Answer (score 5):

Your bug is in

```
http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", self.on_g)
```

which should be

```
http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", on_g)
```

since you defined a function, not a method.

Comment: you should mention, they will also need to remove the `self` from the `on_g` argspec

Comment: how would i use the second code (in the question) to avoid `response` being not declared? because alone, it will work fine and fetch `google`